# Angular 8 FCM receiveMessage() not working when application run in background

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently i am using Firebase cloud messaging for webs push notification in angular.I want to use  custom notification and sound for background message like foreground message but I am not sure how i customize background notification please help.

firebase-messaging-sw.js file code

```
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
    
        console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
        var data = payload.data;
    
    });

self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {

    const data = JSON.parse(event.data.text());

    console.log(data);
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(data.data.title, {"body": data.data.body}));
    // event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(event.notification.title, {"body": event.notification.body}));


});
```

messaging.service.ts code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireMessaging } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'

@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
  currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  constructor(private angularFireMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
      (_messaging) => {
        _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
        _messaging.onTokenRefresh = _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
      }
    )
  }

  requestPermission() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
      (token) => {
        console.log(token);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
      }
    );
  }

  receiveMessage() {
    this.angularFireMessaging.messages.subscribe(
      (payload) => {
        console.log("new message received. ", payload);
         self.audio.play();
        this.currentMessage.next(payload);
        // this.showCustomNotification(payload);
      })
  }
```

Comment: Still finding answer for this issue

Comment: Hi @sujat Have you able to find solution for this issue?